# dot "." insensitive search using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, email, jdbc

I know the following way to do case insensitive search on strings

`criterion.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email).ignoreCase());`

Is there a way to do "." insensitive search i.e. it will ignore any dot that occurs in either of the two strings being compared.

I don't want to fetch the emails and do a comparison in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is to use regular expression in Hibernate but unfortunately there's nothing in the hibernate docs for performing regular expression queries (using HQL or Criteria queries). The approach using the sqlRestrictions should probably be changed to one of the overloaded methods as follows

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("regexp_like({alias}.NODE_1, ?)", re, Hibernate.STRING)
```

Check out if it works for your. Hope it would be help. Let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to store a normalized email (without dots) along with original one and then normalize the given one, and then search by it